# WSL drvfs mount issues — user mapping not recognised?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, mount, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm having a couple of issues with mounting drives in WSL (Win10 Linux Subsystem) -- see separate question about a mount error on a different drive.

I have a network share mounted on drive W: locally - and I have read/write access in Windows.

Mounting this drive with drvfs works fine:

$ sudo mount -t drvfs W: /mnt/w

But - when I want to access the drive:

```
( -/- ) e514678@K46290: ~ $ ls -l /mnt/w
ls: cannot access '/mnt/w/bar': Permission denied
ls: cannot access '/mnt/w/baz': Permission denied
ls: cannot access '/mnt/w/foo': Permission denied
total 0
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? bar
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? baz
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? foo
( -/- ) e514678@K46290: ~ $
```

Again - on Windows I can access the drive, and the subdirectories on the drive.
Mounted using drvfs, I can see the toplevel entries on the drive, but they seem to be missing user & permission information; and so I can't access any of the files from linux either.

Accessing files on a couple of other network shares works fine - but I'm stumped about what's different with this one.

Any ideas as to what might be different with this network volume?
(Trying to mount it with specific uid/gid doesn't help: 'sudo mount -t drvfs -ouid=1000,gid=1000 W: /mnt/w' linux still can't access the drive -- with the same issue).

Comment: btw - has anyone else even seen this issue?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue.

I found WSL introduced `/etc/wsl.conf` since Windows Build 17093.
Please read the details in here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config#configure-per-distro-launch-settings-with-wslconf

This is a simple example that might fix your problem:

```
$ cat /etc/wsl.conf
[automount]
enabled=true
options=metadata,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=022
```

I found the example above from here: [WSL mounted file permissions](https://superuser.com/questions/1275940/wsl-mounted-file-permissions)

After creating or modifying the file, you need to restart WSL.